# R : Repeat rows in a data frame with new set of values for certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

```
employee <- c("John", "Adi", "Sam")
salary <- c(21000, 22000, 23000)
startdate <- as.Date(c("2014-11-01","2014-01-01","2014-10-01"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2015-10-31","2014-12-31","2015-10-31"))
N<- c(2,1,2)
df<- data.frame(employee,salary, startdate, enddate, N)
```

I want to repeat the entire row by "n" number of times where "n" is specified in the column **N** but I want to change the **enddate** in the original row to be fixed date such as "31/12/2014" and make this fixed date as **startdate** in the repeating row. Run the code to see the resultant example (expected output)in **df2**:

```
employee <- c(rep("John",2), "Adi", rep("Sam",2))
salary <- c(21000,21000, 22000, 23000,23000)
startdate <- as.Date(c("2014-11-01","2014-12-31", "2014-01-01","2014-10-01","2014-12-31"))
enddate <- as.Date(c("2014-12-31","2015-10-31","2014-12-31","2014-12-31","2015-10-31"))
N<- c(2,2,1,2,2)
df2<- data.frame(employee,salary, startdate, enddate, N)
```

Comment: I have modified my question, hope this clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the example but in my original data set it is not working. I get the rows repeated same as earlier but start and end date are still same as previous row. Other thing is that I wanted my end date for the first row to be fixed such as 31/12/2014 and use this fixed date to be the start date for the second (or repeated row).

Comment: Apologies but first time asking a question on any blog in this world. I have tried to expand the example and also added the expected output in df2

Comment: This is already added. if you run the code df2 and 6 lines before that, you should see the resultant output

Comment: I have a doubt.  What if the replication is >2

Comment: IN my situation the replication is max 2 but yes from learning perspective 3 is difficult and that's why I did post on blog. For max 2 i can just do it by copying a data.frame and run a replace command seperatly and rbind which is not effective if you have >3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), expand the rows by replicating the 'N' variable.  We get the numeric index ('i1') of the observation (`.I[1L]`) grouped by 'employee', use that to assign (`:=`) the 'enddate' with '2014-12-31'.  Similarly, we get the row index ('i2') of 2nd to last element (`.I[seq_len(.N)>1L]`) for each 'employee' and set the 'startdate' as '2014-12-31'.

```
DT <- setDT(df)[rep(seq_len(.N), N)]
i1 <- DT[,  .I[1L] , by = employee]$V1
DT[i1, enddate:= as.Date('2014-12-31')]
i2 <- DT[, .I[seq_len(.N)>1L], employee]$V1
DT[i2, startdate:= as.Date('2014-12-31')]
identical(as.data.table(df2), DT)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or we can do this using `if` and concatenate the '2014-12-31' for the 'startdate' and 'enddate', grouped by 'employee' and then assign the output back to the columns 'startdate', 'enddate'.

```
DT[, c('startdate', 'enddate') := if(.N>1L) 
            list(c(startdate[1L], as.Date('2014-12-31')),
                 c(as.Date('2014-12-31'), enddate[.N])) , by = employee]
identical(DT, as.data.table(df2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works perfect and now I can expand this too. Just one questions as why did you use $V1 as at the end? You are star

Comment: @Adi When we don't name the output, the data.table create a new column as 'V1'.  By using `$V1`, we are extracting the column.  You can check `DT[, .I[seq_len(.N)>1L], employee]`, it will be a data.table.  It is the same as we extract a column in `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant. I don't I could have figured this out. I still need to do bit of learning on these synatx's

Comment: @Adi It may take some time to get the full grasp of it.  I would try by splitting the codes into simple/small chunks and check the output.  For example in the second piece of code, I would check `DT[, if(.N>1L) c(startdate[1L], as.Date('2014-12-31')), by = employee]` and only in the final step I do the assignment (`:=`)

Comment: Thanks. Will follow the advice

Comment: Just by interest, what will you do if we want to manipulate both start date and end date and not just one of them. This will not work because LHS:=RHS  can be used only in one particular way.

Comment: @Adi Can you post that as a separate question with some example.  It will be much more helpful to understand the problem.